# How can I programmatically record audio and video of the Android Studio emulator screen?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I tried using the `adb screenrecord` command, but it only records the screen without audio. The Extended Controls Record and Playback feature appears to be the only way to record the screen with audio, but it is a manual process. Is there a way to access this tool programmatically to automate the recording of audio and video from the emulator or is there any way that I can use Android Debug Bridge command line tool (`adb`) to do this?

Thank you for your help.

## Extended Controls Record and Playback

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video#record-video-with-the-emulator

## `adb screenrecord` command

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#screenrecord